# Problema para renderizar Slider en App.js React Native

Tags: react-native

Les consulto, estoy teniendo un bug el cual no se donde revisar ya porque no tengo error a la vista y tampoco me marca uno pero no logro renderizar una slider
Revise muchas veces el codigo, investigue pero no encontre solucion quizas me puedan dar una mano para salir de esto.
El resultado que estoy teniendo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberia de verse el Slider arriba de las flatList horizontal

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

En este archivo tengo el codigo:

Slider.js

```
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  Text,
  View
} from "react-native";
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window')

const Slider = props => ( <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={props.uri}/>
    </View>
)

const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      image: {
        flex: 1,
        width
    }    
}


export default class extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            imagesSlider:  [
                require('../assets/img/eljuegodelcalamar.jpg'),
                require('../assets/img/minions.jpg'),
                require('../assets/img/tarzan.jpg')
            ]
        }       
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Swiper
                    autoplay
                    height={240}
                >
                {
                     this.state.imagesSlider.map((item, i) => <Slider
                         uri={item}
                         key={i}
                    />)
                }
                </Swiper>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Luego lo llamo desde App.js para renderizar en device:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import List from './components/List';
import Slider from './components/Slider.js'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={[{flex:1}, styles.container]}>
          <Slider />
          <List />
      </View>

    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    flex: 1
  }
})

export default App
```

Si me pueden ayudar les agradeceria mucho!
Aguardo comentarios.
Saludos.